# Invoke-WebRequest Timeout

Tags: powershell

Trying to so a simple XML file download using the following Powershell script:

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri [target URL] -OutFile [target file] -TimeoutSec 0
```

I keep getting:
        "Invoke-WebRequest: The operation has timed out."
error.  I thought the -TimeoutSec set to 0 was no timeout.  This process can take 15-20 minutes in some cases to download the file.  Am I missing something here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem and looked around for answers. My process takes 5 minutes to execute. What helped me (and I just found the solution a few minutes ago here in stack overflow) was to use BOTH:

```
    [System.Net.ServicePointManager]::MaxServicePointIdleTime = 5000000
```

And at the same time the timeout flag you mentioned, but not setting it to 0 but to a high enough of a value to accommodate your request.